# Returning a value from external php file for use in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

So I have an input of type text that the user can enter text into, and when they post the text I'm using jQuery's prepend method to post it onto the screen, but before I let the text publish, I want it to go through some validation in an external PHP file, but I'm not having much luck on achieving this.

jQuery is sending a POST to the php file and I have a variable with the sanitized text in the php file that's ready to go - I'm just not sure how to return the value (preferably in a good way) back to jQuery.

Here is the POST:

```
$.post('ajaxPost.php', {'message' : msg}, function(){

    $('.messages').prepend(msg + '<br>');

});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your `ajaxPost.php` actually sends some value back? If it does, just add a parameter to your callback `function(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in this way:

```
$.post('ajaxPost.php', {'message' : msg}, function(data){
    $('.messages').prepend(data + '<br>');
});
```

And in your ajaxPost.php you have to return your text you want to display. You can just simply echo it like *echo $sanitized_message;*.

Answer (score -1):

you can echo the resposne in your external php script and use get instead of post

```
$.get('ajaxPost.php?message='+msg, function( data ) {
   $( ".someDiv" ).html( data );
   alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

you might need to url_encode the message before

Comment: Why change from POST to GET? And where is your call to `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: since get request can be cached by the server, I prefer get for sending/retrieving data, that does not require encryption and extra security features.
As i mentioned, he might need to encode his message to be safe. please read carefully next time :)